# Where can I find the git-lfs-authenticate command?

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

I can successfully push a git repository that uses Git LFS to Github, but when I try to push it to my own server I get the following error: `git-lfs-authenticate: not found`.

```
$ git push origin main |& cat
batch request: sh: 1: git-lfs-authenticate: not found: exit status 127
Uploading LFS objects:   0% (0/1), 0 B | 0 B/s, done.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git.example.com:'
```

On the local host, I use `git-lfs/2.13.2` and on the remote host `git-lfs/2.7.1`. These are the current versions of Debian 10 and 11, respectively. I have tried using [the latest version of Git LFS](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/releases/latest) on both hosts by placing the `git-lfs` binary in `/usr/local/bin`. The output is now slightly different, but I still get the same error:

```
$ git push origin main |& cat
batch request: sh: 1: git-lfs-authenticate: not found: exit status 127
error: failed to push some refs to 'git.example.com:'
```

I have also tried searching for a binary named `git-lfs-authenticate` but it is not present in any of the releases of Git LFS. I have also tried reading the [Git LFS Server Documentation](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/master/docs/api/server-discovery.md) which mentions the `git-lfs-authenticate` command, but it doesn't explain where to find it or how to implement it.

Comment: I had this problem and spent several days without any success. In my case, it is git clone from a remote host through ssh. I pushed locally through the file system without any problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You propably just forgot the definition of where `git` will find the LFS-Backend.
As @bk2204 already mentioned and we assume, you checked out your repo via ssh, but most LFS backends do not support ssh connections.

Thus, you'll need to define that all/only LFS-Blobs shall be send to https, even though you may checkout the repo itself via ssh:

```
git clone ssh://git-server.com/foo/bar.git .
git config -f .lfsconfig lfs.url https://git-server.com/foo/bar.git/info/lfs
git add .lfsconfig && git commit -m"define lfs backend" && git push
```

What the correct lfs http url is, depends on your git host.

Answer (score 1):

The protocol of Git LFS is mostly HTTP-based, and the `git-lfs-authenticate` command is used to allow a user to authenticate with a remote server to get authentication credentials to use over the HTTP-based protocol.  Git LFS doesn't currently have a pure SSH-based protocol.

As a result, it's not possible to ship a generic version of this client because it requires interacting with the HTTP server, which can't be done in a generic way.  You could build your own that interacts with your own HTTP server, though.

Comment: I don't understand why, in my case, I have a local sever1 hosting the same lfs.  git clone remote from this server got no problem.  Made a copy of the repo, and served on server2, and clonging from the same remote host, then got the mentioned error message. These computers are all on the same network.