# git push Error batch request: fatal: unrecogized command 'git-lfs-authenticate ~ upload': exit status 128

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree, git-lfs

I am doing software configuration management using git.(with sourcetree)

An error occurs when pushing with a remote branch.

```
batch request: fatal: unrecognized command 'git-lfs-authenticate ~ upload': exit status 128
```

Please tell me the reason for this error and the solution.

Thank you.

Comment: You're using Git-LFS but the server to which you're trying to `git push` does not provide Git-LFS or has a configuration error. See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65982109/1256452) for instance.

Comment: The server configuration needs to be modified. Thank you.